# Visiting a webserver behind a NAT that has a IPv6 ICP IP address

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, firefox, router, ipv6

I set up a webserver behind my xfinity WiFi router/modem. Behind the router, I have 10.0.0.X addresses. My public ISP IP address is an IPv6 address.

When I login to the router/modem and set up port forwarding I set all port 80 requests to the webserver.

When I send a get request to the public ISP IP I get the following error from my firefox webbrowser :

Unable to connect

Firefox can't establish a connection to the server at [my IPv6 address].

Comment: try things other than a  web server. try `nc` in cygwin `nc -l 80` and try port forwarding to that.  And put firefox aside and try an online port scanner like grc.com see if it says open/closed/"stealth". Ignore the FUD on the site, but the scan works, you can enther the port to scan..  want the scan to say oh no Failed port is open, that'd be good. And make sure the windows firewall is letting port 80 through.

Comment: Exactly [which router](http://customer.comcast.com/help-and-support/internet/broadband-gateways-userguides/) do you have?

Comment: You say you have, IPv4 on your LAN, but IPv6 out on the Internet.  Are you running dual-stack (both IPv4 & IPv6, pretty sure most Comcast customers are) or is your external address IPv6 only?

Comment: @heavyd when I go to a website like "whatsmyip" it only shows a single IPv6. So I don't know for sure if I have an ipv4 address or not.

Comment: @Matthew http://test-ipv6.com/ will give you both your IPv4 address and IPv6 address.  I'm assuming you have both.  Many consumer routers don't support IPv6 very well, and I'm assuming you currently only have IPv4 forwarded.